# Adding values by row and have them apply to a single row variable while preserving other variables and rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like,

```
df <- data.frame(num1 = c('a','b','c','d')
                 ,num2 = c(1,2,3,4)
                 ,num3 = c(5,6,7,8)
                 ,num4 = c('x','y','b','d'))
```

And would like the out put to go from

```
num1  num2  num3 num4
a     1     5    x
b     2     6    y
c     3     7    b
d     4     8    d
```

To

```
num1  num2  num3 num4
a     10    26   x 
b     2     6    y
c     3     7    b
d     4     8    d
```

Here is a sample that achieves the result in my own solution

```
df <- data.frame(num1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
                 num2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 num3 = c(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 num4 = c('x', 'y', 'b', 'd'))

sum_summarised <- df %>% 
  filter(grepl('a|b|c',num1)) %>% 
  summarise(num2 = sum(num2), num3 = sum(num3))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(num2 = if_else(num1 == 'a',sum_summarised$num2,num2))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(num3 = if_else(num1 == 'a',sum_summarised$num3,num3))
```

Essentially summing num2/num3 columns and applying the sum to row a variable while preserving original row values for variables b,c, and d and num 4 column values.

Preference would be to use dplyr - I have tried variants of `group_by` and `slice` and `filter` combinations to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated in this unique problem I have faced. Thank you!

Comment: `df[1,2:3] <- colSums(df[,2:3])`

Comment: I want to do a version of this but the issue is my data frame will change dynamically over time and can't rely on indexing the rows.

Comment: In this case `df[df$num1 == "a",c("num2", "num3")] <- colSums(df[,c("num2", "num3")])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to use `rows_update()`. This is a bit more verbose, but I'd say it pays of if we want to construct more complex operations. Below we call `rows_update()` and inside we use `summarise()` first defining the id column we want to join by and then the columns we want to update with `across(), everything else will be untouched.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rows_update(
    df %>%
      summarise(num1 = "a",
                across(num2:num3, sum)),
    by = "num1")

#>   num1 num2 num3 num4
#> 1    a   10   26    x
#> 2    b    2    6    y
#> 3    c    3    7    b
#> 4    d    4    8    d
```

We can also perform more complex operations inside our `tibble` for example if we don't want to sum-up `c` we can `filter()`:

```r
df %>% 
  rows_update(
    df %>%
      filter(num1 != "c") %>% 
      summarise(num1 = "a",
                across(num2:num3, sum)),
    by = "num1")

#>   num1 num2 num3 num4
#> 1    a    7   19    x
#> 2    b    2    6    y
#> 3    c    3    7    b
#> 4    d    4    8    d
```

Data from OP

```r
df <- data.frame(num1 = c('a','b','c','d')
                 ,num2 = c(1,2,3,4)
                 ,num3 = c(5,6,7,8)
                 ,num4 = c('x','y','b','d'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: We could even skip the `tibble`-part and include the key in `summarise`: `rows_update(df, summarise(df, num1 = "a", across(num2:num3, sum)), by = "num1")`

Comment: What are benefits here of using `tibble.frame` vs. `data.frame`? Thank you

Comment: @DreDay: There is no real benefit in this case. Since we are using dplyr, it is shorter to type, but that's about it. Btw, the updated answer doesn't containt a call to `tibble` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a preference for `dplyr`, we could use `across` and `if_else`:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(num2:num3, ~ if_else(num1 == "a", sum(.), .)))
```

Output:

```
  num1 num2 num3 num4
1    a   10   26    x
2    b    2    6    y
3    c    3    7    b
4    d    4    8    d
```

**Update** *if i wanted to to just sum a, b, and c? not all? and apply to a?*:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(num2:num3, ~ if_else(num1 == "a", sum(.[num1 %in% c("a", "b", "c")]), .)))
```

Output:

```
  num1 num2 num3 num4
1    a    6   18    x
2    b    2    6    y
3    c    3    7    b
4    d    4    8    d
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using `transmute()` from 'dplyr' package:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  transmute(num1, 
            num2 = c(sum(num2), num2[-1]), 
            num3 = c(sum(num3), num3[-1]), 
            num4)

  num1 num2 num3 num4
1    a   10   26    x
2    b    2    6    y
3    c    3    7    b
4    d    4    8    d
```